# Kendo dialog box angular 2+ appears inside kendo grid when wrapped inside kendoGridDetailTemplate

Tags: css, angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Is there a CSS way to make Kendo Dialog appear outside of kendo grid when it is wrapped inside **kendoGridDetailTemplate**?

Currently my component looks like:

```
<kendo-grid><div *kendoGridDetailTemplate="let dataItem">
<lookup-list-fields [lookupListId]="dataItem.id"></lookup-list-fields></div></kendo-grid>
```

Here **lookup-list-fields** is my component which contains Kendo dialog box. I have went through solutions which says place kendo dialog outside kendo grid or use Angular Service. I want to know if we can re position dialog using css.
[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UclJ9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why you wrapped a Kendo Dialog inside grid? In my option, It is a improper way.
Can you place the Dialog component outside grid and open the Dialog when you click the grid cell which you want.

Comment: The content of inner grid was quite large due to which I had to make a separate component. Did not want to make it more complex with emitting event to parent component, so included dialog inside it. Anyway I had to take dialog outside at last to solve it.